# Route to ASP.NET Core MVC controller from AJAX returning 404

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

This should be quite simple but I'm not seeing it.

Passing an object to a controller from an AJAX Call. The object is correct. It isn't finding the router.

Ajax in Javascript:

```
$('#employee_table tbody').on('click', '.editLink', function () {
        var data = employee_table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: '/Employee',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _iEmployeeService;
    private readonly ICommentService _iCommentService;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService _iemployeeService, ICommentService _icommentService)
    {
        this._iEmployeeService = _iemployeeService;
        _iCommentService = _icommentService;
    }

    public IActionResult Employee(object obj)
    {
        EmployeeDTO emp = (EmployeeDTO)obj;
        EmployeeDetailViewModel employeeDetailViewModel = new(emp);

        return View(employeeDetailViewModel);
    }
}
```

Error in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()   Employee:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess (and without knowing how controllers are mapped it is just a guess) I would say that you need to invoke `url: '/Employee/Employee'`. The easiest way to confirm is to run your C# code with Swagger - it will tell you exactly what is the right path to the method.

There are other issues with your code... First, you are invoking MVC controller / method from AJAX - what are you going to do with the HTML that you will get back?

Comment: It's an employee object that was sent via a datatable row.  I'm doing this to show the details rather than go back for another query to the DB

Comment: I also have at the top of the controller:  [ApiController]  [Route("Employees")]

Answer (score 1):

As @Felix mentioned, update your code like:

```
$('#employee_table tbody').on('click', '.editLink', function () {
        var data = employee_table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: '/Employee/Employee',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

Also add `HttpPost` above your `Employee` method. It will definitely work.